# trigger list of external Jenkins jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

joblist=[A, B]
//A, B are external job's path
for  (job in joblist)
job build : "{$job}", params

above script for series runs I want to run parallel

Comment: assume length of joblist is n.

Comment: You can check out the following [examples](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel)